# Data validation in AVRO

Tags: rpc, avro, json-rpc, data-serialization, avro4s

I am new to AVRO and please excuse me if it is a simple question.
I have a use case where I am using AVRO schema for record calls.

Let's say I have avro schema

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "namepsace": "xyz",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "CustId", "type":"string"},
        {"name": "SessionId", "type":"string"},
     ]
}
```

Now if the input is like

```
{
    "CustId" : "abc1234"
    "sessionID" : "000-0000-00000"
}
```

I want to use some regex validations for these fields and I want take this input only if it comes in particular format shown as above. Is there any way to specify in avro schema to include regex expression?

Any other data serialization formats which supports something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use a custom [logical type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Logical+Types) for this. You would then include the regular expressions directly in the schema.

For example, here's how you would implement one in JavaScript:

```js
var avro = require('avsc'),
    util = require('util');

/**
 * Sample logical type that validates strings using a regular expression.
 *
 */
function ValidatedString(attrs, opts) {
  avro.types.LogicalType.call(this, attrs, opts);
  this._pattern = new RegExp(attrs.pattern);
}
util.inherits(ValidatedString, avro.types.LogicalType);

ValidatedString.prototype._fromValue = function (val) {
  if (!this._pattern.test(val)) {
    throw new Error('invalid string: ' + val);
  }
  return val;
};

ValidatedString.prototype._toValue = ValidatedString.prototype._fromValue;
```

And how you would use it:

```js
var type = avro.parse({
  name: 'Example',
  type: 'record',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'custId',
      type: 'string' // Normal (free-form) string.
    },
    {
      name: 'sessionId',
      type: {
        type: 'string',
        logicalType: 'validated-string',
        pattern: '^\\d{3}-\\d{4}-\\d{5}$' // Validation pattern.
      }
    },
  ]
}, {logicalTypes: {'validated-string': ValidatedString}});

type.isValid({custId: 'abc', sessionId: '123-1234-12345'}); // true
type.isValid({custId: 'abc', sessionId: 'foobar'}); // false
```

You can read more about implementing and using logical types [here](https://github.com/mtth/avsc/wiki/Advanced-usage#logical-types).

Edit: For the Java implementation, I believe you will want to look at the following classes:

- [`LogicalType`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/LogicalType.html), the base you'll need to extend.
- [`Conversion`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/Conversion.html), to perform the conversion (or validation in your case) of the data.
- [`LogicalTypes`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/LogicalTypes.html) and [`Conversions`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/Conversions.html), a few examples of existing implementations.
- [`TestGenericLogicalTypes`](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/test/java/org/apache/avro/generic/TestGenericLogicalTypes.java), relevant tests which could provide a helpful starting point.

Comment: Is this a feature unique to the javascript library?

Comment: The Java implementation also already supports logical types. They were introduced relatively recently in the spec but should hopefully be in most implementations soon.

Comment: That is awesome example. Is Java implementation released now? Can you point me to the javadocs if possible? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sure @user2166328; I edited my answer with a few links. The Java implementation has been released (`1.8.0+`).

Comment: thank you for the links. that answered my questions. :)

Comment: can you please provide this approach in java implementation for validation using regular expression by Custom LogicalType because i didnt find any resources or relevant information